# CPP llvm build fails with "lvalue required as unary '&' operand" in lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp, why is stdin/out/err not defined?

Tags: android, c++, llvm, lvalue

I am trying to compile the Android SDK on an ARMv7 device  on Debian Wheezy, I am using CM-10.1 source.

The build fails like this:

```
target thumb C++: libLLVMSupport <= external/llvm/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp
external/llvm/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp: In static member function \
    'static void* llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::SearchForAddressOfSymbol(const char*)':
external/llvm/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp:165:5: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
external/llvm/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp:166:5: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
external/llvm/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp:167:5: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
make: *** [/home/edge-case/Android-Lab/system/out/target/product/d2spr/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/\
    libLLVMSupport_intermediates/DynamicLibrary.o] Error 1
```

In that file `lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp` the code it fails at is this:

```
#define EXPLICIT_SYMBOL(SYM) \
   if (!strcmp(symbolName, #SYM)) return &SYM

// On linux we have a weird situation. The stderr/out/in symbols are both
// macros and global variables because of standards requirements. So, we
// boldly use the EXPLICIT_SYMBOL macro without checking for a #define first.
#if defined(__linux__) and !defined(__ANDROID__)
  {
    EXPLICIT_SYMBOL(stderr); // Line 165
    EXPLICIT_SYMBOL(stdout); // Line 166
    EXPLICIT_SYMBOL(stdin);  // Line 167
  }
#else
...
```

I think the code is doing something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("The address of stdout:\t%p\n", &stdout);
    printf("The address of stdin:\t%p\n", &stdin);
    printf("The address of stderr:\t%p\n", &stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

...which compiles cleanly with `gcc 4.6` and the `-Wall` flag.
The output of the test is this:

```
$ ./addr_stdio 
The address of stdout:  0x1064c
The address of stdin:   0x10648
The address of stderr:  0x10640
```

How can I modify the code in the DynamicLibrary.cpp file so that it will do what it is intended to do and compile?

**Edit:**

I changed the code to use explicit if statements instead of macros, like this:

```
//    EXPLICIT_SYMBOL(stdin);
    if (!strcmp(symbolName, "stderr")) return &stderr;
```

...but, compilation failed at the same location with the same error. I guess this means I interpreted the code correctly, and the macro is functioning as intended.

I am assuming this is being cause by stdin|out|err not being defined because the error seems to indicate that they translate to nothing, hence "lvalue required...". Note, when it compiles for the host it works just fine.

So now my new question is, why is stdin|out|err not define when it compiles for the target, and what can I do to solve this issue?

Here is a [link to the git repository](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_llvm/tree/cm-10.1) and here is a [link to the file in question "DynamicLibrary.cpp"](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_llvm/blob/cm-10.1/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed this down to the Android.mk file, it defines a `LOCAL_CFLAG` which never seems to be used in the source code. it is `-D__android__` so I did some `grep`ing around as follows:

```
edge-case@Flubber:~/Android-Lab/system/external/llvm/lib/Support$ grep -rn __android__ ./*
./Android.mk:116:LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__android__
./Android.mk:131:LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__android__
edge-case@Flubber:~/Android-Lab/system/external/llvm/lib/Support$ grep -rni __android__ ./*
./Android.mk:116:LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__android__
./Android.mk:131:LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__android__
./DynamicLibrary.cpp:167:#if defined(__linux__) and !defined(__ANDROID__)
./LockFileManager.cpp:52:#if LLVM_ON_UNIX && !defined(__ANDROID__)


edge-case@Flubber:~/Android-Lab/system/external/llvm/lib/Support$ croot                                
edge-case@Flubber:~/Android-Lab/system$ grep -rn __android__ bionic/
edge-case@Flubber:~/Android-Lab/system$ grep -rni __android__ bionic/
bionic/libc/arch-mips/include/machine/signal.h:60:#if defined(__ANDROID__)
bionic/libc/arch-mips/include/machine/signal.h:107:#ifdef __ANDROID__
bionic/libc/arch-mips/include/machine/signal.h:143:#endif /* __ANDROID__ */
bionic/libc/arch-x86/include/machine/_types.h:41:#  ifdef __ANDROID__
bionic/libc/arch-x86/include/machine/_types.h:54:#  ifdef __ANDROID__
```

As you can see, no where is `__android__` used, except in the `Android.mk` file, not even in Bionic, and the piece of code this is failing at uses `#if ... !defined(__ANDROID__)`.

I changed the flag to `__ANDROID__`, time will tell.

Sure enough:

```
...
target thumb C++: libLLVMSupport <= external/llvm/lib/Support/Dwarf.cpp
target thumb C++: libLLVMSupport <= external/llvm/lib/Support/DynamicLibrary.cpp
target thumb C++: libLLVMSupport <= external/llvm/lib/Support/Errno.cpp
target thumb C++: libLLVMSupport <= external/llvm/lib/Support/ErrorHandling.cpp
...
```

As you can see, compilation succeeded. I hope it was the right thing to do. I probably should have added `-D__ANDROID__` instead of changed the case of the entry that was present, an unused define can't really hurt anything, a missing one can.